# how to change value of variable in another file

Tags: python

I'm working on a pygame roguelike themed survival game and I need to change the value of a variable called chunk that says in which chunk the player is, it starts at 0 and goes on when you reach the edge of the screen.

fileB:

```py
chunk = 0
```

fileA:

```py
import fileB
if(player is out of the screen): fileB.chunk += 1
```

I tried something like this. Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Not sure you are ready to work on a rougelike themed survival game -  maybe some basic tutorials are in order? The code shown does not work that way, and you might profit from looking into basic classes usage so you can get an instance of a class and modify its variables.. Start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: You got to learn to walk before you can run. Thats why I suggested tutorials. Using a class with membervariables and an instance of that is one way to do what you want to do ...

Comment: @Barbo24 your account was probably suspended because of the foul language you're using. You're being disrespectful to the community members who're only trying to help you. Please be considerate. Maybe take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: `fileB.chunk += 1` is not pretty code, but otherwise it is expected to work. Did you find it otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a couple of solutions that you can use for this, but they aren't the prettiest.
You can have a function in fileB which updates the value you want to change:

```
def updateChunks(newValue):
    global chunks
    chunks = newValue
```

You could then import fileB and call the function as follows:

```
fileB.updateChunks(#)
```

You could also have the value of chunks, or any other information in a file and read the file whenever you need. Hope that helps